# Jquery datatable row grouping like microsoft excel

Tags: jquery, datatable, row, grouping

I was wondering if we can build tables like [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7020481/image/Codecall%27s%20javascript%20tree%20and%20table%20view%20tutorial%20-%20Google%20Chrome.jpg)  with **jquery datatable**?!
and if we can, how?!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unless you are ready to write your own custom plugin, it is not possible to make that kind of layout with jquery datatable.

Edit:

I found such a custom plugin, but it does for rows what you want to do with columns, perhaps you could modify it: http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnFakeRowspan

Comment: thanks for your response, may be i find what i am loking for , check this : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/row_grouping_height.html

Comment: I do apologise for my earlier statement. What you have found looks **exactly** what you were looking for.